# is it possible in android to programatically call a person and then let him/her hear a pre-recorded voice/audio?

Tags: android

I want to know if it is possible using public android API's to call a person programatically and then as soon as she picks up the phone, let her hear a pre-recorded voice message/audio?

Before I get comments like why I want to do that, or its a bad user experience, I just want to clarify that the question is more on the technical front than implementation so please do let me know if you have any pointers.

Thnx for your time!

Comment: Read this http://stackoverflow.com/a/5452628/1321873

Comment: adding to @Rajesh link there is a bit more explanation http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9671914/android-manipulating-voice-in-phone-calls#9672524